# Matplotlib Pyplot Pie Chart From CSV File

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, charts

I've got a CSV file with 1 column with values 0 or 1, I'm trying to plot the number of values as a pie chart.

I have tried:

```
fileName = sys.argv[1]
col1 = sys.argv[2]

file = pd.read_csv(fileName)
data = np.array(file)[:,col1]

labels = 'True', 'False'
sizes = data
colors = ['red', 'blue']

plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

But it errors. How can I display a 2 slice pie chart from the CSV column? The values are out of order. I did something similar with a bar chart and it automatically just figured it all out.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pie.py", line 18, in <module>
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
  File "~\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3137, in pie
frame=frame, data=data)
  File "~\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2559, in pie
raise ValueError("'label' must be of length 'x'")
ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'
```

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: @zondo updated question with it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the amount of data (`sizes`) is bigger or less than 2 (number of `labels`). 
Verify that data and labels have the same amount of data:

```
labels = 'True', 'False'
sizes = data
colors = ['red', 'blue']
assert len(sizes) == len(labels)
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

if the assert fails, you must enter more/fewer labels and colors depending on the amount of data in `sizes`.